# Azure function app authorization excludedPaths not working in some environments

Tags: azure, azure-devops, authorization, azure-bicep

We have a devops pipeline running the same bicep templates in multiple environments and it has excludedPaths for 2 end points, one for health for front door and one is the swagger doc for APIM.  It's a function app that used Azure AD SSO for authorization. The template and authorization is working fine in the dev environment but does not work in the test environment, the login works but the excluded paths still give a 401 Unauthorized.  The template is the same file with different parameters passed to it.  If I send a request in postman with the token, swagger.json comes back fine in the test environment.  Health and the swagger doc started coming back fine in dev after the excluded paths were added to the template.  I have tried restarting the function app and re-running the pipeline multiple times.

```
resource apiApp_authsettingsV2 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: apiApp
  name: 'authsettingsV2'
  properties: {
    globalValidation: {
      requireAuthentication: true
      unauthenticatedClientAction: 'Return401'
      excludedPaths: [
        '/api/health'
        '/api/swagger.json'
      ]
    }
    identityProviders: {
      azureActiveDirectory: {
        enabled: true
        registration: {
          clientId: environmentConfig[environment].siteAuthClientId
          openIdIssuer: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/${environmentConfig[environment].openIdIssuer}'
        }
        validation: {
          allowedAudiences: [
            environmentConfig[environment].siteAuthAllowedAudiences
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    login: {
      tokenStore: {
        enabled: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We figured this out, an older configuration ARM template was running after the bicep template and resetting the excluded paths only in the one environment.